# How can i get current module name [nwidart/laravel-modules]

Tags: laravel

How can i get current module name, or current namespace. of laravel
I use this library [nwidart/laravel-modules].

I trid this code but not solve problem

```
$module_name = basename(__FILE__, '.module');
```

Comment: Can you provide more context of where you are trying to make this call and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your modules __construct controller :

```
    private $module_name;
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        $class = get_called_class(); // or $class = static::class;
        $arr_class = explode("\\", $class);
        $this->module_name = $arr_class[1];
    }

    public function index()
    {
        echo $this->module_name;
    }
```

Comment: But how can make this in file helper.php, i don't use in constructor

Comment: you can't, based on [get called class php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php) Returns FALSE if called from outside a class. what do you want to achieve by being able to check the current module name?

Answer (score 1):

To get module entity: `$module = Module::find('blog');`

To get module name: `$module->getName();`

This is documented pretty well by package author here:
https://nwidart.com/laravel-modules/v1/advanced-tools/module-methods

Comment: No, I need to get current active module, this function $module = Module::find('blog');
this function return just blog>
i need to return current module

Comment: I understand - where and why you need it?

Comment: I need to put in helper.php, because return translate by module name

function getFullPathTranslate($key, $value)
{
    return trans('base::admin/' . $key . '.' . $value );
}

Comment: Ok, that needs more clarification. Do you need to get translations from specific module?

Comment: multiple translations

Comment: Can't you use service provider to merge your base translations with module translations and just add a key in module translations? Then you can use standard translations access helpers and just put a module prefix when you want to receive a specific translations.